# How to create a PDF of my web application using AlivePdf

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, alivepdf

I have a large web application with verticalScrollBar with few charts and large datagrid. I am planning to create pdf of my web application using AlivePdf.

Right now, Im using below code to creat a pdf of my application, but no luck.

```
        var printView:DisplayObject  = new InteractionsAnalysis() as DisplayObject;
        printView.width = Application.application.width;
        printView.height = Application.application.height;          

    var printPDF:PDF = new PDF(Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4);
    printPDF.setDisplayMode( Display.FULL_PAGE, Layout.SINGLE_PAGE );
    printPDF.addPage();
    printPDF.addImage(printView,0,0,0,0,"PNG",100,1,ResizeMode.FIT_TO_PAGE);

   var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
   var b:ByteArray = printPDF.save(Method.LOCAL);
   f.save(b);
```

Can anybody give me some directions?

Comment: Do you at least get a "Save File" dialog when calling f.save?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the method which is calling f.save() was triggered due from a user event.  According to the [FileReference doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29):

> In Flash Player, you can only call
>   this method successfully in response
>   to a user event (for example, in an
>   event handler for a mouse click or
>   keypress event). Otherwise, calling
>   this method results in Flash Player
>   throwing an Error exception. This
>   limitation does not apply to AIR
>   content in the application sandbox.